# Get value after reader onload

Tags: javascript

var image is not defined in alert :( please help , thank you so much!

```
handleBeforeUpload (file, event) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = (function () {
     var f = reader.result;
   }); 

   var image = f;
   alert(image)

   var photo = {uri: image}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

Your f variable is in scope of onload function callback. Define it outside of that function, where you define your reader variable, so it will be available in scope of handleBeforeUpload function

```
handleBeforeUpload (file, event) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   var photo = null;
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = (function () {
     f = reader.result;
     photo = { uri: f }
   }); 
}
```

Comment: response null :(

Comment: if after f=reader.result try get console.log , data show, but alert have null (

Comment: i think need use promise ?

Comment: Yes! You are calling async function and your alert is called before onload callback is called. Check updated answer, I added console.log in the callback itself so you can inspect the actual file object in console

Comment: console.log(f);
 return data, but i'm not understand how save this data if you can please build correct version , thank you!.]

Comment: May be out of context , but i just play little with it, may be worth watching , https://jsfiddle.net/parlad/un04n1dg/  , This is complete structure of file part. thank you

Comment: @MarioNikolaus its full code,  save in global var f = ''' now response null in alert

Comment: After  reader.onload = (function () {
     f = reader.result;
     console.log(f); <- have data
   }); alert(f) -> no data

Comment: It will be null, I left it there because it is referenced in question. What does your console log say?

Comment: @MarioNikolaus  console.log(f); response base64 code, how this data send  to    alert(image)
 ?

Comment: So you have your image in that callback, forget about alert that code is wrong, I updated my answer. Do whatever you need to do with image in that callback

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164499/discussion-between-user3006575-and-mario-nikolaus).

Comment: its not good for me , becouse photo will stay null
need return data after onload
maybe must use promise function , after suss return and write data in var photo . Maybe i'm mistake